# Can't use a defined vhost on xampp

Tags: macos, apache

I'm having some trouble configuring my localhost with xampp.

I installed de xampp, removed the # to include httpd-vhosts and then, I set a vhost, like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/teste.pp”
    ServerName teste.pp
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, on my /etc/hosts I set 127.0.0.1 teste.pp

When I access to teste.pp, it does nothing, but if I try to access on localhost/teste.pp it show my test page.

I restarted apache after changing the vhosts.

I'm using sierra.

Answer (score 1):

ok, found the problem.
It was doublequotes ..